# fs.writefile() lost data of image

Tags: node.js, koa2

I use a post request to upload a picture and store the image data in my server but lost some image data:

```js
let storePic = function(imgData) {
    const base64Data = imgData.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
    const dataBuffer = new Buffer.alloc(5000,base64Data, 'base64')
        
    fs.writeFile(imgPath, dataBuffer, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('fail to store image')
        } else {
            console.log('success to store image')
        }
    })
}
```

When I get the image from the server, it is broken:

[image: 1]

Comment: I solve the problem ,the size is too small . new Buffer.alloc(50000,base64Data,'base64')

Answer (score 1):

Should use `Buffer.from(base64Data, 'base64')` instead else its truncated.

Imo its slightly better to match out the image rather then just presume its there:

```
let matches = imgData.match(/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/)

if (matches.length !== 3) new Error('Invalid base64 image URI')

// matches[1] contains the mime-type which is handy for alot of things

fs.writeFile(imgPath, Buffer.from(matches[2], 'base64'), (err) => {
```